# Using .htaccess to redirect all pages except three

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am taking a site permanently offline, but I'm displaying a splash page on it for a week or two before it goes down. How can I edit my .htaccess file to display that splash page? It needs to allow the page itself (root directory) as well as two images in the /images directory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Place the following configuration into your `.htaccess` located in the root of your website:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/splash.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/usedimage.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/anotherusedimage.png$
RewriteRule .* /splash.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just tried it and Chrome reports a redirect loop (error 310).

Comment: @StevenH please doblecheck if the splash.html is listed in the list of `RewriteCond`... is you're sure, try to remove the leading slash `/` in the `RewriteCond`

Comment: Yeah, I verified that `splash.html` is both in the root directory and in the `RewriteCond`. I tried removing the leading `/`, but I still get a redirect loop. There's nothing in the .htaccess file other than the code you gave me (edited for my file names).

Comment: @StevenH the redirect loop means, the `RewriteCond` corresponding with your `splash.html` doesn't match. Have not much idea why is this - the setup works on my computer as written in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I got it -- I had to put a `/` in front of `splash.html` in the `RewriteRule`. That did the trick. Thank you so much!