# URL paths for hyperlinks and images broken with jquery .load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Trying to use forum us a comments section on webpage and avoid iframes at the same time.

```
    <script>
    $('#test').load('./forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=10' function(result) {
    var variable = $('#result').html();
    $(this).find(".topic-title").remove();
    $(this).find(".action-bar").remove();
    $(this).find(".postprofile").remove();
    </script>
```

All links that would point to site.com/forum/linkhere.php   now point to   site.com/linkhere.php   this includes all my calls for scripts in the header, so all of the ajax forms are essentially useless as well. I tried a rewrite like so

```
$('#test a').each(function(){
$(this).prop('src', path + '/' + $(this).prop('src'))
```

and trying with `$('#test script')` as well, and also `path + '/forum'`  but no luck. The contents of this just gets pushed to a div with id="test" at the moment.

Anyone got some tips for me?

```
$(function() {
        $('script').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('text/javascript', function(index, value) {
                if (value.substr(0,1) !== "/") {
                    value = window.location.pathname + value;
                }
                return "https://site[dot]com/forum" + value;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

UPDATE: I had some luck by setting PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '../forum'; in viewtopic.php, this fixed my relative paths issue and started loading all the headers correct. But now once a post is submitted via the ajax form, the post submits successfully, but there's an error refreshing the ajax page .loaded into a div with jquery. Any ideas what this might be? I think it's a jquery/.load issue because the form works fine on the actual forum page.

Comment: It's because the content of the page you're calling uses relative links. So they are transposed to be relative to your current URL. If you don't want this behaviour you will have to loop through all links and update their `href` attributes

Comment: "Anyone got some tips for me?" yes, close the function before `</script>`

Comment: Need to see sample of the affected html in order to modify paths

Comment: It is not feasible for me to do this with every link in phpbb I think so that is why I tried the rewrite like so^ I know the why, I can't get the rewrite working

Answer (score -1):

use full path URLs like
http://yoursite.com/forum/linkhere.php
for every call in your 
viewtopic.php file

-edit:

try using httacces file in your root folder
check this thread :

[Using .htaccess to redirect all pages except three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443243/using-htaccess-to-redirect-all-pages-except-three)

Comment: you can also try using httacces redirect, look at my edited answer

Comment: Only place that allows specifying paths in viewtopic.php is under $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH :     and it won't accept absolute paths. has to be relative to the directory script ran out of as far as I can tell

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (/.*)?$ /forum$1 [L,NC,R=301]     no work, any ideas?