# How to htacess Redirect all pages except one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We need to redirect all pages of oldsite.com to index page of newsite.com with one exception.

I have some dynamic pages that begin with oldsite.com/sync.php which i need to be accessible so i don't want to redirect.

Probably the redirect works with:

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newsite.ro/ [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Can you help, please?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess to redirect all pages except three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443243/using-htaccess-to-redirect-all-pages-except-three)

Comment: The "possible duplicate" is not really the same. I have dynamic pages like http://oldsite.ro/sync.php?tip=item&id=[ID]&code=[CODE] and more which contain "sync.php" that i don't want to redirect. i don't know the syntax to use. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the page uri that you don't want to redirect using `RewriteCond` .

Put the following condition above your `RewriteRule` line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/DoNotRedirect\.php$ [NC]
```